# "compare" or "be compared"

Tags: passive-voice

Here is a sentence:

***We would like to import auto parts from your company on a regular basis, provided your prices compare favorably with those of others.***

Is the sentence right? I think the word "compare" in the sentence should be replaced by "are compared", for in my view COMPARE is a PASSIVE statement. Can anyone tell me which one is right? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is correct as it stands. The verb *compare* can be used both transitively and intransitively with slightly different meanings.

The transitive *compare* means, roughly, *to analyse or state the similarities (and differences) of items*. For example:

> People often compare car prices online.

As a transitive verb with an object, it can be used in the passive:

> Car prices are often compared online.

The intransitive *compare* means, *to be worthy of comparison; to bear comparison with*. The *compare* in the OP's example sentence is being used correctly in this sense and, as a intransitive verb, cannot be made passive.